# Close a Tkinter Window/Frame after 60secs of no activity

Tags: python, tkinter

so I have a frame that appears in my Tkinter GUI. I can auto close (destroy) it after X time (say 10secs) using the code below.

```
frame.after_idle(10000, lambda: frame.destroy())
```

What I need to do is auto close it after 10secs but only if there has been no input from the user during that time, i.e. not clicked or interacted with the frame? I'm not sure how or if you can tell that though? Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Look at the `.after_cancel` method. Basically use `.after_cancel` and schedule a new call to `frame.destroy` using `.after` each time the user interacts with your program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `tk.Frame` is a container and as such has no foot print until it contains some tkinter object.
The object can be anything other than another container.
I have inserted a `tk.Canvas` into the frame and used `bind` to give user feedback to the code.

The code is primed to close the frame if no activity is detected.

The following activities (motion, key, mouse, enter, leave) will reset time delay.

No activity for 10 seconds will automatically close the frame.

```py
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(app)
frame.grid()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
canvas.grid()

# store after
wait = []

def closer():
    # execute it
    frame.destroy()
    print("frame closed")

def reset(event):
    # forestall closure
    canvas.after_cancel(wait.pop(0))
    wait.append(canvas.after(10000, closer))
    print(wait)


canvas.event_add(
    "<<caught>>",
    "<Enter>", "<Leave>", "<Motion>",
    "<ButtonPress>", "<ButtonRelease>",
    "<KeyPress>", "<KeyRelease>")
canvas.bind("<<caught>>", reset)

# prime it
wait.append(canvas.after(10000, closer))

# make sure canvas has the focus (for keyboard input)
canvas.focus_set()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, using after_cancel and the code above has worked. Cheers all, much appreciated